# What is the health bar in Halo games?

Tags: halo-the-master-chief-collection, halo-series

In most Halo games, there's usually a "shield capacity bar" which depletes with damage. When this bar is fully depleted, there's a secondary bar that starts to deplete. What is this bar? What does it represent? Is it the physical health of Master Chief? Is it the strength of the armor? In either case, how does it regenerate?

Comment: If I recall, this would vary from game to game in the series. Halo CE for example had an actual health bar that you needed medkits for to restore, while most of the other games did not have medkits at all. My point being though - are you asking for a specific Halo game or all of them? It's not very clear. I see you tagged "halo" which  doesn't have any guidance, so it's not clear. The Master chief collection has multiple games too.

Comment: @TimmyJim I was looking for a general lore based answer. I didn't see any tags for lore. Something like what Rapitor posted. It's not really specific to any one game, but it might differ between armor models.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: it's the health of master chief and the armor is healing him(in some games) with sci-fi [biofoam](https://www.halopedia.org/Biofoam).

Long answer: This question kind of depends on the game, CE, Reach, 5, and Infinite have a seperate health display while 2, 3, and 4 do not.

In Halo CE, your health does not regenerate on its own and you need to collect medkits throughout the game. At this point, the Mjolnir armor system is MkV.

In Halo 2,3, and 4, the Mjolnir armor system is MkVI, which has Biofoam injectors built into the suit. Capable of keeping the Spartan alive continuously.

In Halo Reach, being a prequel, we're back in MkV... but your health regenerates partially, and needs a  med kit for full recovery. Lore wise is explained as the MkV armor Noble Team uses is modified... game reason is its just more "modern".

In Halo 5, you have a visible health bar regenerates fully on its own using MkVI Gen 2. We're in MKVI so we got the biofoam injectors...

Halo Infinite is a bit of a wild one, since you are able to choose different Mjolnir Systems as part of the customization, but in "actuality"... Master Chief is in MKVI Gen 3 armor while Spartan IVs (your own MP character) is suited with MKVII, both of which equipped with the same internal biofoam and operating systems.